# Cannot convert 'void (MyClass::*)()' to 'void (*)()

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

I'm trying to link the function void MainWindow::lowPower() to wiringPiISR(int, int, void (*)(void). My problem is that I get the following error:

```
cannot convert 'void (MyClass::*)()' to 'void (*)()
```

when i'm trying to point to the function this way:

```
void (MainWindow::*lowPower)(void);
wiringPiISR(4, INT_EDGE_BOTH, lowPower);
```

the syntax of wiringPiISR is:

```
int wiringPiISR (int pin, int edgeType,  void (*function)(void))
```

I can't make the lowPower static because i need to call a few objects

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: In modern C++ you shouldn't be using function pointers (especially since a member function pointer can't be converted to a non-member function pointer, because member functions have a hidden first argument that becomes the `this` pointer in the member function). Instead use [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function).

Comment: If you have no control over the `wiringPiISR` function, then you either can't use a member function, or you have to make it `static`. Optionally if you can you can use a non-capturing [lambda expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).

Comment: thanks for your help Joachim, i solved my problem in another way (see below)

Comment: @Mattis your solution is what Someprogrammerdude suggested: not using a member function. If you ever have more than 1 MainWindow instance, then they will all receive the trigger signal. (That isn't likely, but if you use this technique elsewhere where there are multiple instances, you will have a problem)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I would suggest a template parameter for function-y parameters over `std::function`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution which is maybe not the best way but a possibility:

at the begin of the *.cpp:

```
Trigger trigger;
void interrupt()
{
    emit trigger.triggered();
}
```

Trigger is a very simple class with just one public signal (triggered). This signal is connected to a public slot in the MainWindow class in its default-constructor where also wiringPiISR is declared as:

```
wiringPiISR(0, INT_EDGE_BOTH, *interrupt);
```

I know that this is no perfect solution because it uses a function-pointer, but I didn't want to change the code of the wiringPi.h respectively wiringPi.c.